# awk for loop with leading zeros in variable

Tags: awk

I want to run a `for` loop in `awk` with leading zeros in the index variable.

This isn't for *printing* a number with leading zeros, which I could easily handle with a `printf` statement.  It's for checking if the given number (with leading zeros) has been used as an index in an array.

So what I actually want is to iterate through *string* values in `awk`, from "01" to "14" (or whatever).

Something like:

```
myarray["01"]
myarray["02"]
myarray["04"]
myarray["05"]
# ... etc, up to "12"

for (i = 01; i <= 12; i++) {
  if (! (i in myarray)) {
    print i " is missing from myarray"
  }
}
```

Should report that "03 is missing from myarray."  But that's not how it works.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `sprintf`:

```
BEGIN {
  myarray["01"]
  myarray["02"]
  myarray["04"]
  myarray["05"]
  # ... etc, up to "12"

  for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    k = sprintf("%02d", i)
    if (! (k in myarray)) {
      print k " is missing from myarray"
    }
  }
}
```

gave you:

```
03 is missing from myarray
06 is missing from myarray
07 is missing from myarray
08 is missing from myarray
09 is missing from myarray
10 is missing from myarray
11 is missing from myarray
12 is missing from myarray
```